# Git: revert merge after creating a new branch

Tags: git, version-control

I've merged branch A with master and created branch B. However, I've since discovered that branch A has things that need doing.

Is there a way of reverting to this earlier state?

If branch B is lost in the process, it's not a problem.

Comment: Unless you deleted A after you merged, you can just `git checkout A` again, do the additional work, and then re-merge... If necessary, you can then either rebase B to start at a different commit, or simply also merge the new A into B to adjust it for the changes...

Comment: @twalberg I just commented on the first answer about something which appears to be what you're recommending. I'll have a try.

Answer (score 2):

Branch names are just labels on the commit graph in your repository.  Put the labels wherever you want.  [`git reflog`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) will tell you where the merge was, then e.g.

```
git checkout -B master ${thatcommit}^
```

will reset the `master` branch to the merge's first parent.  See the [`gitrevisions` manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to see all the ways to identify things to git.

Comment: Just a thought, but I use Github for Mac, and when I switch to branch A, I'm given the option of editing it, even though it's been merged. I'm wondering if this is the same thing as you mention, but simplified.

Comment: That's right.  Commits matter. Branch names don't.  @twalberg's answer  in comments looks like a better way, it treats your situation rather than your question.

Comment: Okay, I've made the edits to branch A and merged again, but now I have conflicts, but it isn't clear from the documentation ( https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts ) what I'm supposed to do; do I make a manual edit — in which case, do I remove the markup Git adds — or do un-check the files I don't want in Github?

Comment: The former: merge left markers where it can't tell what's right.  make the files right and commit.

Comment: So if it says:

<<<<<<< HEAD
 I don't want this.
=======
 I do want this.
>>>>>>> hotfix_17

I remove everything except for: "I do want this." yes? I ask because I just tried it and the conflict marker in Github remains on the file.

Comment: Then you committed files without resolving the conflicts -- now it looks like you had the right idea all along: if no one has pulled from your github repo, reset your labels and force push, to get the github repo to just abandon the bad commits you're going to redo.  edit: note that individual repos are _entirely_ separate entities.  Any and every relation between two repos is purely a matter of convenience.

Comment: I've not synchronised with Github.com yet. Also, I've not committed anything yet, either. I've just made the changes. Having removed the conflict mark-up, do I now commit the changes?

Comment: re the first, if github is showing content, it was committed in and pushed from some other repo. 2nd: yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I followed the advice of @twalberg:

> Unless you deleted A after you merged, you can just git checkout A
>   again, do the additional work, and then re-merge... If necessary, you
>   can then either rebase B to start at a different commit, or simply
>   also merge the new A into B to adjust it for the changes...

This gave me the option to once again make changes. However, this caused conflicts, which I resolved by following the instructions according to [Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts), with thanks to @jthill for his time and further explanations.